# Split of one folder (with images) into two and move images to the new folder

Tags: r, split, directory

I have one folder, called **train**, which contains two subfolders **hot_dog** and **not_hot_dog**. Out of the first folder **train** I would like to randomly select images from both subfolders **hot_dog** and **not_hot_dog** and put them into a new folder, called **validation**. This validation folder has again two subfolders, called **hot_dog** and **not_hot_dog**. The amount of randomly selected images should be approx. 20% of the original amount of images. Those images which were randomly selected and saved under the new folder **validation**, should be deleted in the original folder **train**.

Current folder structure looks like this:

[image: current folder structure]

The end result of the folder structure should look like this:

[image: target folder structure]

Comment: Hi Lexal, welcome to Stack Overflow. You tagged this question with [R]. Is that because you intended to perform this task with the R statistical programing language? If so, have to tried any code yet? If the answer is yes, it will be easier to help working off your code. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: Hey - yes. My intention is to run this code in [R]. As I am quite a beginner with coding, I could not really produce any code, which would be useful in this forum. Why did you remove R in my header? I do not want to get a Python answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, set the current working directory to the path where the folder `train` is located by `setwd()`. Then run the following code:

```
# setwd("path/to/folder/train")
path1 <- file.path("train", c("hot_dog", "not_hot_dog"))
path2 <- file.path("validation", c("hot_dog", "not_hot_dog"))
dir.create("validation")
lapply(path2, dir.create)
Map(function(x, y){
  file <- dir(x) ; n <- length(file)
  file_selected <- file.path(x, sample(file, ceiling(n * 0.2)))
  file.copy(file_selected, y)
  file.remove(file_selected)
}, path1, path2)
```

Comment: This was also a really good solution. I tried it out and it worked. Unfortunately also here the files that I moved to the new folder "validation", still exist in the old folder "train". I have to have them deleted in the old folder "train".

Comment: @Lexal If any answers have solved your problem, please mark the preferable one as "accepted". Read [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/412699) for more details about accepting an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach that may work for you. It is not what I would call elegant, but it's relatively easy to understand.

Be sure to replace `~/Stack Overflow/` with whatever directory your `train` directory is located in.

In short, we use `dir.create` to make the new directories (if they do not exist already). Then we use `list.files` to make a list of the files in each of the two training directories. Then we use `sample` to take a sample of those files. Lastly we use `file.copy` to place them into their new home.

```
setwd("~/Stack Overflow/")
sample.fraction <- 0.2
train.true.dir <- "train/hot_dog"
train.false.dir <- "train/not_hot_dog"
valid.true.dir <- "validation/hot_dog"
valid.false.dir <- "validation/not_hot_dog"
sapply(c("validation",valid.true.dir,valid.false.dir),function(x){dir.create(x,showWarnings = FALSE)})
true.files <- list.files(train.true.dir)
false.files <- list.files(train.false.dir)
true.sample <- sample(true.files,size = ceiling(length(true.files) * sample.fraction))
false.sample <- sample(false.files,size = ceiling(length(false.files) * sample.fraction))
sapply(true.sample,function(x){file.copy(paste(train.true.dir,x,sep="/"),paste(valid.true.dir,x,sep="/"))})
sapply(false.sample,function(x){file.copy(paste(train.false.dir,x,sep="/"),paste(valid.false.dir,x,sep="/"))})
```

If you wanted to remove those files afterwards, you could use these two lines.

**Please make a backup first.**

```
sapply(true.sample,function(x){file.remove(paste(train.true.dir,x,sep="/"))})
sapply(false.sample,function(x){file.remove(paste(train.false.dir,x,sep="/"))})
```

Comment: Unbelievable...that was my first stack overflow question and I get a (correct!!!) answer within 20 min. You made my day!!!

Comment: One more issue I figured out: With the code I was able to move 20% of the original files to the new folder "validation". Unfortunately those 20% pictures still stayed in the folder "train". My intention was, that I more or less shift those 20% from the folder "train" to the new folder "validation".

Comment: I edited my answer with a way to remove those files. Please be sure to make a backup.

Comment: Really nice. Now it works as expected. Great. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code which I then used:

````
path2 <- file.path(here(), "data/hot-dog-not-hot-dog/validation", c("hot_dog", "not_hot_dog"))
dir.create(file.path(here(), "data/hot-dog-not-hot-dog/validation"))
lapply(path2, dir.create)
Map(function(x, y){
  file <- dir(x) ; n <- length(file)
  file_selected <- file.path(x, sample(file, ceiling(n * 0.2)))
  file.copy(file_selected, y)
  file.remove(file_selected)
}, path1, path2)```
````